# Use slim/temple as template extension in beego

Tags: go, slim-lang, beego

Its possible to use [golib/temple](https://github.com/golib/temple) or any other template engines like "slim lang" in beego framework?

Beego documentation mentions its possible to use [beego.AddTemplateExt here](http://beego.me/docs/quickstart/view.md).

Thanks!

Comment: `AddTemplateExt` appears to only support using a different file extension, not a different template language. (See http://beego.me/docs/mvc/view/view.md.) My guess from skimming the documentation is that it's not possible to ask Beego to use a different template engine.

Comment: I guess you are right but I resist myself to view it as impossible. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Oh! Wait! Its possible to use pongo2 for example, but it requires [an extension](https://github.com/oal/beego-pongo2).

Comment: How about using mruby or using sys-calls to compile the templates?